# Java run curl command is different between Windows and Linux

Tags: java, linux, windows, curl

I use Spring Boot to write a api server, run on 192.168.24.102:7000,which accept restful api to create an app. Here is the problem I meet and even I finally solve it but I don't understand why?

When the curl command run on Linux, it is success, like this:

> curl "https://192.168.24.102:7000/app/registerbyip" -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -k -d "{\"ip\": \"192.168.24.102\", \"appType\": 5, \"appName\": \"efg\"}"

[image]

When the curl command run on Windows cmd it is also success, like this:

[image]

So the curl command is right, then I write it into Java code

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TestDemo {
    public static String exeCurl(String[] cmds) {
        ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder(cmds);
        Process p;
        try {
            p = process.start();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String[] cmd = {"curl",
            "https://192.168.24.102:7000/app/registerbyip", "-k", "-H",
            "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            "-X", "POST",
            "-d", "{\"ip\": \"192.168.24.102\", \"appType\": 5, \"appName\": \"efg\"}"};
        System.out.println(exeCurl(cmd));
    }
}
```

when this java code run on windows, the server will report exception like below:

> {"timestamp":"2019-11-15T02:09:33.261+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"JSON parse error: Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting double-quote to start field name; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('i' (code 105)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 3]","path":"/app/registerbyip"}

**But I copy the java .class file to the linux, the run it will be success.
Why? the same code run on Windows will fail but in linux will success.**

Finally I fix the java curl code like this:

```java
String[] cmd = {"curl",
    "https://192.168.24.102:7000/app/registerbyip", "-k", "-H",
    "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    "-X", "POST",
    "-d", "{\"\"ip\"\": \"\"192.168.24.102\"\", \"\"appType\"\": 5, \"\"appName\"\": \"\"efg\"\"}"};
```

Then it will be success by add another \", but this java code will fail when run on Linux.

[image]

So here is my question? Why will it happen? Why the java code should add another \" sign?  Please help, Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TomMinor I supplied the link. I suggest you read the rules, too.

Comment: Please show the code and/or state the errors. Please don't use links to images. The text is missing from the question. The text on the picture is too small for some people to read. The text on the image cannot be indexed by search engines for future visitors. Also see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/608639)

Comment: @TomMinor Take it "hard". For some country, the images are not accessible due to network restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the client curl perform differently on different platform!

On windows , the param curl -d content,the string content  show like:

```
{\"a\":\"123\"}  (in java "{\\\"a\\\" : \\\"123\\\"}")
```

or

```
{""a"":""123""}  (in java "{\"\"a\"\" : \"\"123\"\"}")
```

can be considered as `{"a":"123"}`  by client curl.

On linux or mac, the -d content shown like :
`{"a":"123"}` , the curl consider it as `{"a":"123"}`.